Design considerations for type traits for a set of related types
The C++ standard library provides std::char_traits<T> to unify the handling of character data without regard to the specific character type used.
It also provides <type_traits> for more general metaprogramming.
These two kinds of traits systems have a different different design: std::char_traits<T> is a class template (with several specializations) that has several static methods.  <type_traits> provides free-standing templates instead of static methods.
Why do these two systems take different approaches?
I'm not seeking opinions.  I'm hoping to identify constraints that should be considered when designing a traits system.

Is there something you can do in one approach that you cannot do in the other?
Has the language evolved to better suit one approach or the other?  (<type_traits> was standardized in C++11; std::char_traits<T> is older)
Do the different approaches reflect a difference in the problem spaces?  (general metaprogramming versus unified handling for a specific finite set of types)

I'm currently designing version two of a collection of traits for a specific domain.  In choosing between a class template with static methods or a collection of standalone templates, I realized I don't know what factors should be considered.

ETA:  A specific distinction between the problem spaces, which might go to my third bullet proof above, is that std::char_traits<T> mostly provides methods of operating on data but <type_traits> are mostly about operating on types.

I would note that in addition to char_traits<T>, there's also numeric_limits<T>, iterator_traits<T>, allocator_traits<T>

Classes like std::basic_string take character traits as a template parameter. For that, the traits need to be encapsulated in a class.

Two excellent answers so far.  They've given me a lot to think about.
I'm digesting it all a while longer before I select an answer.


Do the different approaches reflect a difference in the problem spaces? (general metaprogramming versus unified handling for a specific finite set of types)

Nowadays, if you want to group a set of related functions without clobbering everybody, you'd probably write those functions as free-standing, and use a namespace to group them. After all, in the case of class with static methods, the call site looks like
the_trait_class<some_type>::the_func

and you must have specialized the_trait_class for some_type, so you have written each the_func for each some_type; in the case of free-standing functions in a namespace, the call site looks like
the_trait_namespace::the_func<some_type>

and you must have specialized each the_func for each some_type.
It's fundamentally the same amount of code, with the difference being where <some_type> is written at the call site, for the same effect.
More on it here.

Is there something you can do in one approach that you cannot do in the other?

Well, you can inherit from a class, so you can think of scenarii where you want to pass some object of class derived from std::char_trait around; there's even an example on cppreference. But I think the standard could have provided a similar freedom even if char_traits was implemented via free functions.

Has the language evolved to better suit one approach or the other? (<type_traits> was standardized in C++11; std::char_traits is older)

I think the reason for char_trait to be implemented the way it is, is mostly historical, and nowadays I'd abandon struct+static functions in favour of namespace+free functions.


Why do these two systems take different approaches?

As for free functions versus method functions, several parameters versus a class, the coupling differ.
That result in several pros/cons:

So classes which need those information passed will have to choose between

template <typename T, typename AllTrait = MyTrait<T>>
struct MyClass;

or
template <typename T, typename Trait1 = MyTrait1<T>, typename Trait2 = MyTrait2<T>, ...>
struct MyClass;


Another concern is work to do for the implementation of the traits.

Individual traits allow simple implementation (is_pointer<T*>)
whereas if you group them, you have to either to have those private helper trait for grouping one, or specializing the whole class for each type to consider.

Linked to precedent point is for types which allow user-customization.

It would require to specialize the whole type, and not just the concerned traits.

Is there something you can do in one approach that you cannot do in the other?

I don't see any.

Has the language evolved to better suit one approach or the other?
(<type_traits> was standardized in C++11; std::char_traits<T> is older)
Do the different approaches reflect a difference in the problem spaces? (general metaprogramming versus unified handling for a specific finite set of types)

Most type_traits can be implemented before C++11 (the ones which cannot mostly are the ones which requires compiler help, and is not from the above choice), and nothing change in C++11.
C++20 allows to partial specialize thanks to concept, but applies to both forms.
